# Why is inversion used in "...than do apes in the wild"?

Tags: inversion, comparative-constructions, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I wanted to know why there is inversion in the last part of the following sentence.

> Apes raised by humans seem to protect more frequently than **do apes** in the wild.

Comment: In comparative clauses like "do apes in the wild" in your example the subject can occur after the verb. The effect of the inversion is to place a contrastive subject in end position. It resembles a blend between subject preposing and subject-verb inversion, a property that is found only in comparative clauses.

Comment: @BillJ Care to make that an answer?

Comment: It is merely a stylistic choice.

Comment: The example's intransitive use of *protect* is not idiomatic, BTW. You have to protect a thing, transitive, or protect *from, against, etc.*  One can not merely protect.  *Mary protects,* does not work.

Comment: Then [research the issue](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)! You can search for "subject-verb inversion" or a similar term. If the sources that you find don't explain why inversion is used in situations like this one, or they are not clear, then please explain in your question why you couldn't find the answer on your own.

Comment: The sentence isn't actually correct. Where did you find this quote?  A subject is required for the verb "to protect".  It's a transitive verb. What are they protecting?

Answer (score 0):

> *Apes raised by humans seem to protect more frequently than do apes in*
> *the wild*.

In comparative clauses like "do apes in the wild" in your example, the subject can occur after the verb. The effect of the inversion is to place a contrastive subject in end position.

It resembles a blend between subject preposing and subject-verb inversion, a property that is found only in comparative clauses.